# Does clover report coverage of failed unit tests also

Tags: java, unit-testing, clover

I am using clover to calculate the code coverage of my unit tests. I am getting a certain percentage with around 64 tests failing. Just wanted to know whether the failed tests are also contributing to the amount of code covered percentage or not?

Answer (score 0):

First, please note that Clover records two kinds of code coverage:

- global coverage - from entire test run, this will always contain code coverage from all tests (and not only tests, also from setUp methods etc)
- per-test coverage - code coverage is tracked for every test individually

In case of the per-test coverage you can select whether coverage from failed tests should be included or not. You can configure this option for report generation. See:

- for Ant - the 'clover-report' task, 'current' element, the  includeFailedTestCoverage="true|false" attribute
- for Maven - clover:clover goal, you have to use  tag to change the setting

You can also toggle this in IDE (a coloured bar on editor margin will change):

- in IDEA - View -> Toolbar - enable it, find "Include coverage from passed tests only" button on the tool bar (the one with a green circle and the "OK" label)
- in Eclipse - Coverage Explorer view, "Include coverage from passed tests only" button

References:

- https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CLOVER/clover-setup

Cheers
Marek